# Backbone view hierarchies / regions

Tags: backbone.js

I'm struggling with understanding how to use Backbone routers and views.  I would like a URL such as: `index.html#/products/list` to first call a universal view to insert basic page scaffolding into the DOM, and display items like a global logo.  Then to call a products view, which inserts some general "product" DOM elements.  Then to call a "list" view, which displays a list of products.

If I do something like:

```
var router =  Backbone.Router.extend({
      initialize : function() {
        new HeaderView({el:"#header"}).render();
      },
```

Then the `initialize` routine is only called when the page is first loaded.  If something clears the header, then navigating back to the route doesn't redisplay it because the router already exists, and so `initialize` isn't called again.

I can obviously set up a route like: `"/products/list"/` to call a function, but then that function needs to take care of drawing the entire page, which is code that would need repeated inside all routes, and makes the whole thing "upside down".

I've looked at things like Marionette, but that looks like it could be a sledgehammer to crack a nut.

Finally I could abandon Backbone.Router altogether, and have one big global view, which does it's own delegation to subviews by parsing the URL, but that can't be correct either!

Is there an easy way to have this "hierarchy" of views?

Comment: No, you haven't missed anything. You'd have to create something by yourself. The easiest would be to forbid your user to get directly to this page, therefore being sure your views are all set correctly. I could input some general information about the behavior of Backbone routers if you wish. There could maybe be something you don't know that would help you figure out what you'll do.

Comment: I'd like the user to be able to link directly into pages, so that isn't an option unfortunately.  I'll look into Marionette more I think.  Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think Marionette adds any extension to the router.